# nextjs app rendering blank homepage and blocking redirects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hosting, web-hosting

So I recently deployed my nextjs app on netlify and everything went well except for the fact that when I navigate to the base url of my website, instead of the homepage being displayed I just get a blank screen. if I navigate to specific pages of my site they load completely fine, and I can navigate to the home page from there via buttons, but no matter how many times I type in the base link or refresh it still shows up completely blank without rendering anything.

wondering if anyone has experienced a similar issue and knows a fix because right now it seems like I've exhausted all my options. the site was pure react before I converted it to next today for SEO purposes, and this whole situation really has me regretting the decision as it worked completely fine before.

update: I have now tried moving the contents of my home page from index.js to home.js, and just redirecting to url.com/home from there. index.js now redirects to home.js, but still doesn’t render and leaves me at a blank page when navigating to url.com. I also tried adding redirects in the proper format via next.config.json, _redirects, and netlify.toml, but in all three cases once the changes were deployed my base url still just showed a blank screen and didn’t redirect anywhere. manually typing in 'url.com/home' gets me to my homepage and the site works perfectly fine from there but obviously it's a major issue that the base url for my site just displays a blank screen.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: people are saying to add code but I don't see how any of that is relevant at the moment considering it seems to be a netlify issue based on the fact that the hosting provider doesnt pick up any of my attempts to add redirects (whether next.config.json, _redirects, or netlify.toml). my code runs fine locally and the redirects work as they should, whatever issue it is clearly happens at the hosting level.

Answer (score 0):

update: the issue was apparently with netlify because as soon as I switched providers the issue disappeared and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).